# Python program to perform t-test on frequency list

Tags: python, statistics

hey so i have the following hurdle in my analysis of data.

I have two frequency lists contained in two seperate text files, that look like this:

list2.txt

```
325 de
309 het
308 is
289 een
258 ik
208 rt
207 op
192 :
189 van
186 met
178 echt
167 en
160 in
150 dat
```

list2.txt

```
528 het
471 ik
466 een
445 de
426 is
350 dat
308 niet
273 van
239 en
227 wat
215 die
199 je
193 met
188 op
180 in
166 te
155 voor
```

**OPTION 1:**
I am looking for a way, preferably python, to perform the following equation on the following data. 
This is the formula i am trying to implement:

```
Pm(w) = relative frequency of word/token 'w' in list1
Pv(w) = relative frequency of word/token 'w' in list2
variance = sqrt (Pm(w) / Nm + Pv(w) / Nv)
t = ( Pm(w) - Pv(w)) / variance
```

Could somebody help me write a program/function that does this for me. i.e. it takes both text files as input, and produces a t value for each word/token. Im quite lost, and this seems to be taking me forever.

output: new document with t-test values and words.

**OPTION2:**
i am also looking for a way that produces a ratio for me.

Input:(list1.txt and list2.txt)

Output: (list1-ratio.txt)

```
325  de  445 de  0.7:1
289 een  466 een  0.6:1
```

Output: (list2-ratio.txt)

```
445 de  325 de  1.3:1
466 een  289 een 1.6:1
```

Is there anyone that can help me with this, best case scenario would be to use both options, so i can compare data. This isnt homework, im working on sentiment analysis.

thanx

Comment: If you just want to calculate the result, does [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) help?

Comment: As for the ratio calculation, a simple way of doing this would be to put the lists in dicts, with each word as a dictionary key.

Comment: For Option 1: Nm and Nv is it the Number of occurences of 'w' in list1 resp. 'w' in list2 ? I see no problem coding it, but you should show some effort.

Comment: @kiltek yes thats the case, believe me this problem has been bugging me for days now. Im not the best at statistics, or programming...but im slowly learning

Comment: @Evert it does point me in the right direction, im not too good with programming this. But how do you suggest i go about doing this? Any advice? Im gonna have a more thorough look now.

Comment: additional question: Inside the two textfiles, per line there is this type of element "number" "space" "variable length letters" ???

Comment: @RHK-S8 If you're really new to programming, you might prefer [R](http://www.r-project.org/) for statistical analysis instead. If you want to learn Python, I'm afraid you'll just have to start at [the beginning](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), and search for some numpy tutorials as well.

Comment: i know a method not using scipy, built-in functions only

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `ttest_rel` from `scipy.stats`. This performs a t-test for related data from two samples. In order to do such a test, assume a count of 0 for all words that are not in a list (e.g., "die" is in list2, but not in list1, so count of die in list1 is 0).

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_rel
def input_file_to_dict(f):
    return dict((key, int(value)) for value, key in map(lambda line:line.split(), f))

with open("16892486/list1.txt") as f:
    word_counts1 = input_file_to_dict(f)

with open("16892486/list2.txt") as f:
    word_counts2 = input_file_to_dict(f)

#find all words that are in list1 and in list2
common_words = set.intersection(set(word_counts1.keys()), set(word_counts2.keys()))

t,p = ttest_rel([word_counts1[k] for k in common_words],
                [word_counts2[k] for k in common_words])
```

For requirement two, we can then simple calculate the results we need and write it to a file:

```
with open("16892486/list1-ratio.txt","w") as f_out:
    for word, count1, count2 in zip(all_words, counts1, counts2):
        ratio = float(count1) / count2 if count2>0 else np.inf
        print >>f_out, count1, word, count2, word, "%.2f:1" % ratio
```

Output in the file is then:

```
192 : 0 : inf:1
150 dat 350 dat 0.43:1
325 de 445 de 0.73:1
0 die 215 die 0.00:1
178 echt 0 echt inf:1
289 een 466 een 0.62:1
167 en 239 en 0.70:1
309 het 528 het 0.59:1
258 ik 471 ik 0.55:1
160 in 180 in 0.89:1
308 is 426 is 0.72:1
0 je 199 je 0.00:1
186 met 193 met 0.96:1
0 niet 308 niet 0.00:1
207 op 188 op 1.10:1
208 rt 0 rt inf:1
0 te 166 te 0.00:1
189 van 273 van 0.69:1
0 voor 155 voor 0.00:1
0 wat 227 wat 0.00:1
```

Notes:

- Are you sure you want the format 1.70:1 for the ratio?
- I assign "inf" to the ratio if count2 is zero
- I use string formatting to only output 2 digits after the dot.

Comment: Im trying to get your function to work in a loop, so that it prints the format `word t and p`, it doesnt seem to be working. it merely prints 1 set

Comment: @Thornsten Kranz any idea how to do this?

Comment: I think you missunderstand the idea of a t-test. With just one sample being in each set for the t-test, you cannot do any statistics. You need to "estimate" some properties of the underlying distribution for each set, so you need samples that are big enough. Maybe you can explain your underlying question a little bit more, than I might be able to help you out.

Comment: this is the error i made, i called it a t-test...wen i shouldnt have. If you look at the equation i gave above, it works out the variance and produces a value t. I believe it does this for each word pair, allowing me to find out the variances between these words.